A Cryptic Cryptic "Crossword", Redux
This puzzle is a sequel to A Cryptic Cryptic "Crossword". Knowledge of that puzzle is not required to solve this one.
Welcome back. I've got 12 more cryptic clues for you; each now is six words, cluing a six-letter word. Unfortunately, once again, the boxes they go into decidedly do not take the form of a crossword:

And here are the clues:


Beth, I see, sacrificed her morals (6)
Confusing styles are wily without peer (6)
Court is heartless when in triplicate (6)
Inside healthy people this happens often! (6)
Puts off being rested, changes instead (6)
Scale used to concoct “Ave Maria” (6)
Scattered, right-handed, obsessed person to start (6)
Shi, tough ally, to end nobly (6)
The ocean as Neil crosses it (6)
Thicken rings: add a fifth uranium (6)
Type of tango with a knife (6)
Zero-gravity, careless revenge is more fair (6)


Unfortunately, I forgot the numbers this time (how clumsy of me!)
Anyway, the answer should be something that's good to have. And if you're stuck, the solution that contains the letter E the most should go in the left grid. Good luck!

The clues can be solved like so:

 (-b)ETH+I+C+S SLYEST* TR(i->IN)AL IN+HALE DETERS* _OCT AVE_ TO+_SSED _HI _GH _LY SALINE* CALL(U)S STYLE+T EVENER(-g)*(I'm not entirely sure about some of these parses)

Next, we note that these words form

 two word squares:Taking the indicated cells in the indicated order, we find that a SECOND CHANCE is something that is good to have.


That was quick! Nice work, again.

One thing I missed, though you got the word right: rot13(gevany) was meant to be rot13(gev(-oh)any)
